# Getting Suggestions while installing Laravel through Composer

Tags: laravel, composer-php

Since yesterday when I am creating a laravel project via

```
composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel project_name
```

I am getting these suggestion messages. Is this normal or have I messed something up.

I have Xampp installed with PHP 7.0.1. Switched the PHP option in wamp from 7.0.1 to 5.x.x (there was only one option, dont remember the exact one) and since then I am getting these messages whether I create a new project or add a package via comopser require command. I switched PHP version back to 7.0.1 in Wamp. Uninstalled wamp, but teh messages were still there. Unsitalled xamp, re-installed it but still getting these messages.

> symfony/var-dumper suggests installing ext-intl (To show region name in time zone dump)
>
> symfony/var-dumper suggests installing ext-symfony_debug ()
>
> symfony/routing suggests installing doctrine/annotations (For using the annotation loader)
>
> symfony/routing suggests installing symfony/config (For using the all-in-one router or any loader)
>
> symfony/routing suggests installing symfony/dependency-injection (For loading routes from a service)
>
> symfony/routing suggests installing symfony/expression-language (For using expression matching)

and a long list like this

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This is normal. Some packages can have suggestions but they are not necessary for your Laravel application. Those packages might be useful in some cases but for sure are not required to run or create Laravel application so you can safely ignore those messages.

I've just verified installing 5.5 version of framework and I'm getting the following list of suggestions:

```
symfony/var-dumper suggests installing ext-intl (To show region name in time zone dump)
symfony/var-dumper suggests installing ext-symfony_debug ()
symfony/routing suggests installing doctrine/annotations (For using the annotation loader)
symfony/routing suggests installing symfony/config (For using the all-in-one router or any loader)
symfony/routing suggests installing symfony/dependency-injection (For loading routes from a service)
symfony/routing suggests installing symfony/expression-language (For using expression matching)
symfony/routing suggests installing symfony/yaml (For using the YAML loader)
paragonie/random_compat suggests installing ext-libsodium (Provides a modern crypto API that can be used to generate random bytes.)
symfony/event-dispatcher suggests installing symfony/dependency-injection ()
symfony/http-kernel suggests installing symfony/browser-kit ()
symfony/http-kernel suggests installing symfony/config ()
symfony/http-kernel suggests installing symfony/dependency-injection ()
symfony/console suggests installing symfony/lock ()
egulias/email-validator suggests installing ext-intl (PHP Internationalization Libraries are required to use the SpoofChecking validation)
ramsey/uuid suggests installing ircmaxell/random-lib (Provides RandomLib for use with the RandomLibAdapter)
ramsey/uuid suggests installing ext-libsodium (Provides the PECL libsodium extension for use with the SodiumRandomGenerator)
ramsey/uuid suggests installing ext-uuid (Provides the PECL UUID extension for use with the PeclUuidTimeGenerator and PeclUuidRandomGenerator)
ramsey/uuid suggests installing moontoast/math (Provides support for converting UUID to 128-bit integer (in string form).)
ramsey/uuid suggests installing ramsey/uuid-doctrine (Allows the use of Ramsey\Uuid\Uuid as Doctrine field type.)
ramsey/uuid suggests installing ramsey/uuid-console (A console application for generating UUIDs with ramsey/uuid)
symfony/translation suggests installing symfony/config ()
symfony/translation suggests installing symfony/yaml ()
monolog/monolog suggests installing aws/aws-sdk-php (Allow sending log messages to AWS services like DynamoDB)
monolog/monolog suggests installing doctrine/couchdb (Allow sending log messages to a CouchDB server)
monolog/monolog suggests installing ext-amqp (Allow sending log messages to an AMQP server (1.0+ required))
monolog/monolog suggests installing ext-mongo (Allow sending log messages to a MongoDB server)
monolog/monolog suggests installing graylog2/gelf-php (Allow sending log messages to a GrayLog2 server)
monolog/monolog suggests installing mongodb/mongodb (Allow sending log messages to a MongoDB server via PHP Driver)
monolog/monolog suggests installing php-amqplib/php-amqplib (Allow sending log messages to an AMQP server using php-amqplib)
monolog/monolog suggests installing php-console/php-console (Allow sending log messages to Google Chrome)
monolog/monolog suggests installing rollbar/rollbar (Allow sending log messages to Rollbar)
monolog/monolog suggests installing ruflin/elastica (Allow sending log messages to an Elastic Search server)
monolog/monolog suggests installing sentry/sentry (Allow sending log messages to a Sentry server)
league/flysystem suggests installing league/flysystem-aws-s3-v2 (Allows you to use S3 storage with AWS SDK v2)
league/flysystem suggests installing league/flysystem-aws-s3-v3 (Allows you to use S3 storage with AWS SDK v3)
league/flysystem suggests installing league/flysystem-azure (Allows you to use Windows Azure Blob storage)
league/flysystem suggests installing league/flysystem-cached-adapter (Flysystem adapter decorator for metadata caching)
league/flysystem suggests installing league/flysystem-eventable-filesystem (Allows you to use EventableFilesystem)
league/flysystem suggests installing league/flysystem-rackspace (Allows you to use Rackspace Cloud Files)
league/flysystem suggests installing league/flysystem-sftp (Allows you to use SFTP server storage via phpseclib)
league/flysystem suggests installing league/flysystem-webdav (Allows you to use WebDAV storage)
league/flysystem suggests installing league/flysystem-ziparchive (Allows you to use ZipArchive adapter)
league/flysystem suggests installing spatie/flysystem-dropbox (Allows you to use Dropbox storage)
league/flysystem suggests installing srmklive/flysystem-dropbox-v2 (Allows you to use Dropbox storage for PHP 5 applications)
laravel/framework suggests installing aws/aws-sdk-php (Required to use the SQS queue driver and SES mail driver (~3.0).)
laravel/framework suggests installing doctrine/dbal (Required to rename columns and drop SQLite columns (~2.5).)
laravel/framework suggests installing ext-pcntl (Required to use all features of the queue worker.)
laravel/framework suggests installing ext-posix (Required to use all features of the queue worker.)
laravel/framework suggests installing guzzlehttp/guzzle (Required to use the Mailgun and Mandrill mail drivers and the ping methods on schedules (~6.0).)
laravel/framework suggests installing league/flysystem-aws-s3-v3 (Required to use the Flysystem S3 driver (~1.0).)
laravel/framework suggests installing league/flysystem-cached-adapter (Required to use Flysystem caching (~1.0).)
laravel/framework suggests installing league/flysystem-rackspace (Required to use the Flysystem Rackspace driver (~1.0).)
laravel/framework suggests installing nexmo/client (Required to use the Nexmo transport (~1.0).)
laravel/framework suggests installing pda/pheanstalk (Required to use the beanstalk queue driver (~3.0).)
laravel/framework suggests installing predis/predis (Required to use the redis cache and queue drivers (~1.0).)
laravel/framework suggests installing pusher/pusher-php-server (Required to use the Pusher broadcast driver (~3.0).)
laravel/framework suggests installing symfony/dom-crawler (Required to use most of the crawler integration testing tools (~3.3).)
laravel/framework suggests installing symfony/psr-http-message-bridge (Required to psr7 bridging features (~1.0).)
psy/psysh suggests installing ext-pcntl (Enabling the PCNTL extension makes PsySH a lot happier :))
psy/psysh suggests installing ext-posix (If you have PCNTL, you'll want the POSIX extension as well.)
psy/psysh suggests installing ext-pdo-sqlite (The doc command requires SQLite to work.)
psy/psysh suggests installing hoa/console (A pure PHP readline implementation. You'll want this if your PHP install doesn't already support readline or libedit.)
filp/whoops suggests installing whoops/soap (Formats errors as SOAP responses)
sebastian/global-state suggests installing ext-uopz (*)
phpunit/phpunit-mock-objects suggests installing ext-soap (*)
phpunit/php-code-coverage suggests installing ext-xdebug (^2.5.5)
phpunit/phpunit suggests installing phpunit/php-invoker (^1.1)
phpunit/phpunit suggests installing ext-xdebug (*)
```

and there is no problem with this installation. For example `monolog/monolog` suggests installing `ext-mongo` but obviously I don't want it and I don't need it so it's safe to ignore this suggestion, same for all the others.

Comment: but why have these messages started appearing suddenly?

Comment: @NicoleJavery You might be installing different version of Laravel which uses different versions of Symfony packages with new suggestions or you install the same Laravel version but new Symfony packages appeared with those suggestions.

Comment: its not just symfony, there are a lot of suggestions a very long list. I have only pasted a few

Comment: As I said each package might have its own suggestions so you might get quite a long list of suggestions. I've updated also my answer with list I'm getting - it's safe to ignore them :)

Comment: Suggestion means the package owner think that it's only compulsory to include those packages if you want. For example, check out `vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Mail/composer.json`. There is this `suggest` section tells you that, mails is working fine but if you need to use Mailgun or Mandrill, do include `guzzlehttp/guzzle`. The idea of this is not to include everything at once to overload us, but only include it when you need it.

Comment: @MarcinNabiałek you are right, thanks for your time and help. I created a virtual machine, installed a new os on that and a fresh xampp and composer and then did a laravel project creation and still getting the same messages. I was only confused because it all started after the wamp installation and everything. Though it was a chance that the last package and laravel installation was done before that and the messages are perhaps just recently added in laravel installation

Answer (score 0):

I've just verified installing 7.0.0 version of framework and I'm getting the following list of suggestions:

```
C:\xampp\htdocs>composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel vcs-appoinment
Installing laravel/laravel (v7.0.0)
  - Installing laravel/laravel (v7.0.0): Downloading (100%)
Created project in vcs-appoinment
> @php -r "file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');"
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Package operations: 93 installs, 0 updates, 0 removals
  - Installing voku/portable-ascii (1.4.9): Downloading (100%)
  - Installing symfony/polyfill-ctype (v1.14.0): Loading from cache
  - Installing phpoption/phpoption (1.7.2): Loading from cache
  - Installing vlucas/phpdotenv (v4.1.1): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/css-selector (v5.0.5): Downloading (100%)
  - Installing tijsverkoyen/css-to-inline-styles (2.2.2): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/polyfill-mbstring (v1.14.0): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/var-dumper (v5.0.5): Downloading (100%)
  - Installing symfony/routing (v5.0.5): Downloading (100%)
  - Installing symfony/process (v5.0.5): Downloading (100%)
  - Installing symfony/polyfill-php72 (v1.14.0): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/polyfill-intl-idn (v1.14.0): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/mime (v5.0.5): Downloading (100%)
  - Installing psr/log (1.1.2): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/polyfill-php73 (v1.14.0): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/http-foundation (v5.0.5): Downloading (100%)
  - Installing psr/event-dispatcher (1.0.0): Downloading (100%)
  - Installing symfony/event-dispatcher-contracts (v2.0.1): Downloading (100%)
  - Installing symfony/event-dispatcher (v5.0.5): Downloading (100%)
  - Installing symfony/error-handler (v5.0.5): Downloading (100%)
  - Installing symfony/http-kernel (v5.0.5): Downloading (100%)
  - Installing symfony/finder (v5.0.5): Downloading (100%)
  - Installing psr/container (1.0.0): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/service-contracts (v2.0.1): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/console (v5.0.5): Downloading (100%)
  - Installing symfony/polyfill-iconv (v1.14.0): Loading from cache
  - Installing doctrine/lexer (1.2.0): Loading from cache
  - Installing egulias/email-validator (2.1.17): Loading from cache
  - Installing swiftmailer/swiftmailer (v6.2.3): Loading from cache
  - Installing paragonie/random_compat (v9.99.99): Loading from cache
  - Installing ramsey/uuid (3.9.3): Downloading (100%)
  - Installing psr/simple-cache (1.0.1): Loading from cache
  - Installing opis/closure (3.5.1): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/translation-contracts (v2.0.1): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/translation (v5.0.5): Downloading (100%)
  - Installing nesbot/carbon (2.31.0): Downloading (100%)
  - Installing monolog/monolog (2.0.2): Loading from cache
  - Installing league/flysystem (1.0.64): Loading from cache
  - Installing league/commonmark (1.3.1): Downloading (100%)
  - Installing dragonmantank/cron-expression (v2.3.0): Loading from cache
  - Installing doctrine/inflector (1.3.1): Loading from cache
  - Installing laravel/framework (v7.0.4): Downloading (100%)
  - Installing fideloper/proxy (4.3.0): Downloading (100%)
  - Installing asm89/stack-cors (1.3.0): Downloading (100%)
  - Installing fruitcake/laravel-cors (v1.0.4): Downloading (100%)
  - Installing ralouphie/getallheaders (3.0.3): Loading from cache
  - Installing psr/http-message (1.0.1): Loading from cache
  - Installing guzzlehttp/psr7 (1.6.1): Loading from cache
  - Installing guzzlehttp/promises (v1.3.1): Loading from cache
  - Installing guzzlehttp/guzzle (6.5.2): Loading from cache
  - Installing jakub-onderka/php-console-color (v0.2): Loading from cache
  - Installing jakub-onderka/php-console-highlighter (v0.4): Loading from cache
  - Installing nikic/php-parser (v4.3.0): Loading from cache
  - Installing dnoegel/php-xdg-base-dir (v0.1.1): Loading from cache
  - Installing psy/psysh (v0.9.12): Loading from cache
  - Installing laravel/tinker (v2.2.0): Loading from cache
  - Installing scrivo/highlight.php (v9.18.1.1): Downloading (100%)
  - Installing filp/whoops (2.7.1): Loading from cache
  - Installing facade/ignition-contracts (1.0.0): Loading from cache
  - Installing facade/flare-client-php (1.3.2): Downloading (100%)
  - Installing facade/ignition (2.0.1): Downloading (100%)
  - Installing fzaninotto/faker (v1.9.1): Loading from cache
  - Installing hamcrest/hamcrest-php (v2.0.0): Loading from cache
  - Installing mockery/mockery (1.3.1): Loading from cache
  - Installing nunomaduro/collision (v4.1.2): Downloading (100%)
  - Installing sebastian/version (2.0.1): Loading from cache
  - Installing sebastian/type (1.1.3): Loading from cache
  - Installing sebastian/resource-operations (2.0.1): Loading from cache
  - Installing sebastian/recursion-context (3.0.0): Loading from cache
  - Installing sebastian/object-reflector (1.1.1): Loading from cache
  - Installing sebastian/object-enumerator (3.0.3): Loading from cache
  - Installing sebastian/global-state (3.0.0): Loading from cache
  - Installing sebastian/exporter (3.1.2): Loading from cache
  - Installing sebastian/environment (4.2.3): Loading from cache
  - Installing sebastian/diff (3.0.2): Loading from cache
  - Installing sebastian/comparator (3.0.2): Loading from cache
  - Installing phpunit/php-timer (2.1.2): Loading from cache
  - Installing phpunit/php-text-template (1.2.1): Loading from cache
  - Installing phpunit/php-file-iterator (2.0.2): Loading from cache
  - Installing theseer/tokenizer (1.1.3): Loading from cache
  - Installing sebastian/code-unit-reverse-lookup (1.0.1): Loading from cache
  - Installing phpunit/php-token-stream (3.1.1): Loading from cache
  - Installing phpunit/php-code-coverage (7.0.10): Loading from cache
  - Installing doctrine/instantiator (1.3.0): Loading from cache
  - Installing phpdocumentor/reflection-common (2.0.0): Loading from cache
  - Installing phpdocumentor/type-resolver (1.1.0): Downloading (100%)
  - Installing webmozart/assert (1.7.0): Loading from cache
  - Installing phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock (5.1.0): Downloading (100%)
  - Installing phpspec/prophecy (v1.10.3): Downloading (100%)
  - Installing phar-io/version (2.0.1): Loading from cache
  - Installing phar-io/manifest (1.0.3): Loading from cache
  - Installing myclabs/deep-copy (1.9.5): Loading from cache
  - Installing phpunit/phpunit (8.5.2): Loading from cache
voku/portable-ascii suggests installing ext-intl (Use Intl for transliterator_transliterate() support)
symfony/var-dumper suggests installing ext-intl (To show region name in time zone dump)
symfony/routing suggests installing symfony/config (For using the all-in-one router or any loader)
symfony/routing suggests installing symfony/yaml (For using the YAML loader)
symfony/routing suggests installing symfony/expression-language (For using expression matching)
symfony/routing suggests installing doctrine/annotations (For using the annotation loader)
symfony/polyfill-intl-idn suggests installing ext-intl (For best performance)
symfony/event-dispatcher suggests installing symfony/dependency-injection
symfony/http-kernel suggests installing symfony/browser-kit
symfony/http-kernel suggests installing symfony/config
symfony/http-kernel suggests installing symfony/dependency-injection
symfony/service-contracts suggests installing symfony/service-implementation
symfony/console suggests installing symfony/lock
egulias/email-validator suggests installing ext-intl (PHP Internationalization Libraries are required to use the SpoofChecking validation)
swiftmailer/swiftmailer suggests installing ext-intl (Needed to support internationalized email addresses)
swiftmailer/swiftmailer suggests installing true/punycode (Needed to support internationalized email addresses, if ext-intl is not installed)
paragonie/random_compat suggests installing ext-libsodium (Provides a modern crypto API that can be used to generate random bytes.)
ramsey/uuid suggests installing ext-libsodium (Provides the PECL libsodium extension for use with the SodiumRandomGenerator)
ramsey/uuid suggests installing ext-uuid (Provides the PECL UUID extension for use with the PeclUuidTimeGenerator and PeclUuidRandomGenerator)
ramsey/uuid suggests installing moontoast/math (Provides support for converting UUID to 128-bit integer (in string form).)
ramsey/uuid suggests installing ramsey/uuid-console (A console application for generating UUIDs with ramsey/uuid)
ramsey/uuid suggests installing ramsey/uuid-doctrine (Allows the use of Ramsey\Uuid\Uuid as Doctrine field type.)
ramsey/uuid suggests installing paragonie/random-lib (Provides RandomLib for use with the RandomLibAdapter)
symfony/translation suggests installing symfony/config
symfony/translation suggests installing symfony/yaml
monolog/monolog suggests installing graylog2/gelf-php (Allow sending log messages to a GrayLog2 server)
monolog/monolog suggests installing doctrine/couchdb (Allow sending log messages to a CouchDB server)
monolog/monolog suggests installing ruflin/elastica (Allow sending log messages to an Elastic Search server)
monolog/monolog suggests installing elasticsearch/elasticsearch (Allow sending log messages to an Elasticsearch server via official client)
monolog/monolog suggests installing php-amqplib/php-amqplib (Allow sending log messages to an AMQP server using php-amqplib)
monolog/monolog suggests installing ext-amqp (Allow sending log messages to an AMQP server (1.0+ required))
monolog/monolog suggests installing ext-mongodb (Allow sending log messages to a MongoDB server (via driver))
monolog/monolog suggests installing mongodb/mongodb (Allow sending log messages to a MongoDB server (via library))
monolog/monolog suggests installing aws/aws-sdk-php (Allow sending log messages to AWS services like DynamoDB)
monolog/monolog suggests installing rollbar/rollbar (Allow sending log messages to Rollbar)
monolog/monolog suggests installing php-console/php-console (Allow sending log messages to Google Chrome)
league/flysystem suggests installing league/flysystem-eventable-filesystem (Allows you to use EventableFilesystem)
league/flysystem suggests installing league/flysystem-rackspace (Allows you to use Rackspace Cloud Files)
league/flysystem suggests installing league/flysystem-azure (Allows you to use Windows Azure Blob storage)
league/flysystem suggests installing league/flysystem-webdav (Allows you to use WebDAV storage)
league/flysystem suggests installing league/flysystem-aws-s3-v2 (Allows you to use S3 storage with AWS SDK v2)
league/flysystem suggests installing league/flysystem-aws-s3-v3 (Allows you to use S3 storage with AWS SDK v3)
league/flysystem suggests installing spatie/flysystem-dropbox (Allows you to use Dropbox storage)
league/flysystem suggests installing srmklive/flysystem-dropbox-v2 (Allows you to use Dropbox storage for PHP 5 applications)
league/flysystem suggests installing league/flysystem-cached-adapter (Flysystem adapter decorator for metadata caching)
league/flysystem suggests installing league/flysystem-sftp (Allows you to use SFTP server storage via phpseclib)
league/flysystem suggests installing league/flysystem-ziparchive (Allows you to use ZipArchive adapter)
laravel/framework suggests installing ext-memcached (Required to use the memcache cache driver.)
laravel/framework suggests installing ext-pcntl (Required to use all features of the queue worker.)
laravel/framework suggests installing ext-posix (Required to use all features of the queue worker.)
laravel/framework suggests installing ext-redis (Required to use the Redis cache and queue drivers.)
laravel/framework suggests installing aws/aws-sdk-php (Required to use the SQS queue driver, DynamoDb failed job storage and SES mail driver (^3.0).)
laravel/framework suggests installing doctrine/dbal (Required to rename columns and drop SQLite columns (^2.6).)
laravel/framework suggests installing league/flysystem-aws-s3-v3 (Required to use the Flysystem S3 driver (^1.0).)
laravel/framework suggests installing league/flysystem-cached-adapter (Required to use the Flysystem cache (^1.0).)
laravel/framework suggests installing league/flysystem-sftp (Required to use the Flysystem SFTP driver (^1.0).)
laravel/framework suggests installing moontoast/math (Required to use ordered UUIDs (^1.1).)
laravel/framework suggests installing nyholm/psr7 (Required to use PSR-7 bridging features (^1.2).)
laravel/framework suggests installing pda/pheanstalk (Required to use the beanstalk queue driver (^4.0).)
laravel/framework suggests installing pusher/pusher-php-server (Required to use the Pusher broadcast driver (^4.0).)
laravel/framework suggests installing symfony/cache (Required to PSR-6 cache bridge (^5.0).)
laravel/framework suggests installing symfony/psr-http-message-bridge (Required to use PSR-7 bridging features (^2.0).)
laravel/framework suggests installing wildbit/swiftmailer-postmark (Required to use Postmark mail driver (^3.0).)
guzzlehttp/psr7 suggests installing zendframework/zend-httphandlerrunner (Emit PSR-7 responses)
guzzlehttp/guzzle suggests installing ext-intl (Required for Internationalized Domain Name (IDN) support)
psy/psysh suggests installing ext-pcntl (Enabling the PCNTL extension makes PsySH a lot happier :))
psy/psysh suggests installing ext-posix (If you have PCNTL, you'll want the POSIX extension as well.)
psy/psysh suggests installing ext-pdo-sqlite (The doc command requires SQLite to work.)
psy/psysh suggests installing hoa/console (A pure PHP readline implementation. You'll want this if your PHP install doesn't already support readline or libedit.)
filp/whoops suggests installing whoops/soap (Formats errors as SOAP responses)
facade/ignition suggests installing laravel/telescope (^2.0)
sebastian/global-state suggests installing ext-uopz (*)
sebastian/environment suggests installing ext-posix (*)
phpunit/php-code-coverage suggests installing ext-xdebug (^2.7.2)
phpunit/phpunit suggests installing phpunit/php-invoker (^2.0.0)
phpunit/phpunit suggests installing ext-soap (*)
phpunit/phpunit suggests installing ext-xdebug (*)
Writing lock file
Generating optimized autoload files
> Illuminate\Foundation\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump
> @php artisan package:discover --ansi
Discovered Package: [32mfacade/ignition[39m
Discovered Package: [32mfideloper/proxy[39m
Discovered Package: [32mfruitcake/laravel-cors[39m
Discovered Package: [32mlaravel/tinker[39m
Discovered Package: [32mnesbot/carbon[39m
Discovered Package: [32mnunomaduro/collision[39m
[32mPackage manifest generated successfully.[39m
> @php artisan key:generate --ansi
[32mApplication key set successfully.[39m
```

and there is no problem with this installation.